# Crashing with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am saving JSON in `NSUserDefaults`. When I retrieve a `NSArray`, it's crashing for accessing one of my JSON keys and showing *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x174676fc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key s.'

```
NSDictionary *status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@”today”];
        NSArray *ch =  [status valueForKey:@"c"];
        NSArray *service1 =  [status valueForKey:@"s"];
        NSArray *eventList = [status valueForKey:@"l"];
        NSArray *time = [eventList valueForKey:@"s"];
        NSArray *dur = [eventList valueForKey:@"d"];
        NSArray *eveid = [eventList valueForKey:@"e"];
        NSArray *title = [eventList valueForKey:@"t"];
```

It's crashing at 5 line of code.

Comment: When requesting help on a crash, please post the full symbolicated stack trace and exact error message.

Comment: You need to check that "eventList" isn't nil...

Comment: I have checked & it's not nil , added condition also if evenList count is greater then 0 then only execute further statements

Comment: Despite what you think, `status` is an NSString,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** *You are getting an `NSString` back from `NSUserDefaults`, not the `NSDictionary` you expect.*

Your exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x174676fc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key s.'

Indicates that `status` is an instance of `NSString`, not `NSDictionary`.
This line:

```
NSDictionary *status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@”today”];
```

Is returning an `NSString`. When you call `-valueForKey:` the receiver does not support that key, so it throws an `NSUnknownKeyException` exception. The solution here is to validate what you get from `NSUserDefaults` is what you expect.

Does it respond to `-valueForKey:`?

Does it support the key you are using?

Is it an `NSDictionary`?

Are you setting the `NSUserDefaults` value for `today` with a string elsewhere in your application when you meant to use a dictionary?

All of these things are worth checking.

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to use `valueForKey:` in combination with JSON data. Instead, use `objectForKey:`, which is the `NSDictionary` method.

```
NSDictionary *status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"today"];
NSArray *ch =  [status valueForKey:@"c"];
NSArray *service1 =  [status valueForKey:@"s"];
```

Additionally, I propose you use the modern and shorter syntax:

```
NSDictionary *status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"today"];
NSArray *ch =  status[@"c"];
NSArray *service1 =  status[@"s"];
```

BTW.: Are all elements in `status` of type array? That's a bit surprising.

Comment: It's crashing at 2 nd line with -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17484bee0 error

Comment: That would indicate that element *today* (assigned to *status*) isn't a dictionary, but an array. Please show the full user settings data structure.

Comment: @Colo : You are right , <__NSArrayM 0x170456230>(
{
    c = 558;
    l =     (
                {
            d = 3000;
            e = 1081;
            g = 0;
            gk = "";
            gt = "";
            s = "2015-01-25 12:20 AM";
            t = "Building The Future";
        },               So now i have converted to NSArray but its now giving  error like *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x174676fc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key s.'

Comment: Your user defaults data contain completely different data types then you expect. The code in your question probably contains 5 or more errors. Resolving them one by one doesn't really work on Stack Overflow. I propose you start a new question that contains the entire user settings data structure (and not just an excerpt as above).